# typo3 4.7 recreate database

Tags: typo3, typo3-4.5

Is it possible to recreate the database from scratch on a typo3 4.7.10?

After a migration the database got lost and only the files are available. My job now is to create a new database for it.

Do I have to install a typo3 4.7 and then use this database or is it somehow possible to recreate the database with the current installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an empty db via phpMyAdmin, for example.

Then go to **Install Tool** -> **Basic Configuration** and enter your db credentials there. After that you can switch to **DB analyzer** and click on "Compare" button.

TYPO3 will then prompt all the SQL queries it will perform, which in your case will be "*CREATE TABLE ...*". Just agree with that and your **empty** TYPO3 db will be created.

Comment: nice to know. I have not found it so I did a new install to get the basic database.